# php variale in bracket, where it come from

Tags: php, variables

I use a program call php easy calendar. Into that, there is a lot of php file, most of them good php or HTML. In some file, there is some variable written in bracket like [time] [date] and so on.... it output a perfect valid value nicely formatted...

because the content of the file that DO something are encrypted with ioncude (what a shame) i cannot learn how they do that... is it a php function or a template engine...

can you explain to me, how to get a echo of a variable by telling it's name like [name]

please share the light !

---

### maybe it's a template system, because when i try to use php function, it just don do anything

as request here is the code in file modern.php

```
<!--head-->
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.tableListings {
    width: 450px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-color: #666666;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
    padding-left: 0px;
    font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 15px;
}
.tableDate {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tableTitle {
    color: #812459;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.tableCategory {
    width: 8px;
}
.tableDescr {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.tableTime {
    color: #000000;
    font-weight: normal;
}
.newDate {
    color: #000000;
}
.newTime {
    color: #666666;
}

-->
</style>
<!--head-->


<!--body-->
<table class="tableListings" [mouseover]>
  <tr>
<!--    <td align="left" valign="top" class="tableCategory s2[category]">-->    
<td align="left" valign="top" >
    <span class="tableDate">[date]</span> - <span class="newTime">[time]</span><br />
    <span class="tableTitle">[title]</span>
    <span class="tableDescr">[descr]</span>
<!--    <span class="tableDescr">[categories]</span>
    <span class="tableDescr">[category]</span>
-->        
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--body-->

<!--foot-->

<!--foot-->

<!--empty-->
<table border="0" class="tableListings tableTime">
  <tr>
    <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF"><center>
      Il n'y a pas d'&eacute;v&eacute;nement au calendrier
    </center></td>
  </tr>
</table>
<!--empty-->
```

Comment: It's an array index for an "associative" array (rather than an "innumerated" array), although it should be in quotes unless there's also a constant defined called time. - http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: it would be easier if you showed us some code samples

Comment: Questions about code syntax without any code are really hard to answer. A line of code would say so much more than a thousand words.

Comment: PLEEEEEEEEEESE dont close it.... i need an answer !

Comment: You already got your answer from Mark Baker. Look at the link he provided. It's not the easiest reading but it explains the values in brackets that you're seeing and how to create them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's some sort of custom template feature.
It's not any functionality that PHP ships with out of the box.

As for how to do that yourself, a very quick and dirty way are regular expressions:

```
$replacements = array('foo' => 'f00', 'bar' => 'b4r');
echo preg_replace_callback('/\[(\w+)\]/', function ($match) use ($replacements) {
    return $replacements[$match[1]];
}, $template);
```

It may be much simpler or much more complicated than this, there are infinite ways to do this.

Comment: How to execute php in template system ?